# Yii user types different to 'admin'

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Using gii for creating CRUD for an entity, it creates in each controller an `accessRules()` function, that looks like this:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

This basically tells Yii to allow **authenticated** users to perform 'create' and 'update' actions, and to allow **admin** users to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions.

In my application there is another type of user, the **HouseAdmin** user, with a different role between simple authenticated users and superusers.

With help from here I have created a isHouseAdmin() function that tells if an user is of type HouseAdmin. Now, I need to use that information to make the accessRules() works with 'houseAdmin' users, so I can make rules like:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
    array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('index','view'),
        'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('houseAdmin'),
        ),
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

How could I do this?
Where are those 'admin' and '@' defined so I can add my 'houseAdmin'?

Answer (score 0):

**admin** and **houseAdmin** are the names of the roles. So the should be specified with key **roles**, but not **users**:

```
array('allow',
    'actions' => array('create','update'),
    'roles' => array('houseAdmin'),
),
```

Read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand that. But how do I tell Yii that a user has role 'houseAdmin'?

Comment: You should assign this role to the user. Read these articles: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/136/getting-to-understand-hierarchical-rbac-scheme/    http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control